# How can I pop fragment from backstack without resuming it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I pop fragment from backstack without resuming it? I just want to remove from back stack, I don't want to display it.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've notice that my app crashes at about 140 Fragments in the backstack, so I want to start removing the oldest ones at about 100 Fragments but have not found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's architectural question.

1)Suppose we have 2 controllers (fragments/activities): controller A and controller B.
Both of them connected to one instance of some Model (you may use binding with service, Singleton pattern or init model in Application-heir class and make a getter to it).
When something interesting happens in controller B, he notifies model about it and then model calls controllerA.finish() / controllerA.remove().
Of course, I always try to implement this solution as nicely as possible, but there is a main idea.

2)In another circumstances, I call finish() immediately after startActivity(intent);

3)Also I may write: startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) and after finishing second activity method onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent) is called - if requestCode's are equal, I finish the activity.

Comment: Fragment has no finish method.

Comment: May you insert simple check right in onResume() or in onStart() - if there is need to remove?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a FragmentTransaction's method 
`public abstract FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)`
 to add it to the back stack. There will not be a need to remove it.

Comment: I need to remove specific fragment from back stack. popBackStack doesn't work since it resumes specified fragment.

Comment: What are the flags being used in popBackStack. try using POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE.

Comment: Yes I've used this flag. OnResume of backstack entry is still called.